# Excel - How to search for a date with in date range which are in 2 columns

Tags: excel

[image]
How to search for given date in date range which are in columns and get multiple results as comma separated in excel?
Please see screenshot. Input is in  F2 and output should look like G2.

Comment: To do it using worksheet formulas alone, you'll need to have the TEXTJOIN function (requires Excel 2016 with Office 365). Otherwise, you'll require VBA. Please confirm.

Comment: how it can be done using TEXTJOIN?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, as per my comment, that you have access to the `TEXTJOIN` function (Excel 2016 with Office 365), then, in `G2`, **array formula****:

`=TEXTJOIN(",",1,IF(B$2:B$4<=F2,IF(C$2:C$4>=F2,A$2:A$4,""),""))`

Copy down as required.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: sorry dude, Just checked i have excel 2013, so textjoin did not work.. any alternate solution? please suggest